# Core Graphics: How can I efficiently draw a small section of a large UIBezierPath in a given rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics

The issue is quite straight forward:

• I have a very large and complex `UIBezierPath` that I need to draw
• `drawRect` is called, but with a rect much smaller than the entire path
• Performance is crucial, so it would make sense to only draw parts of the path that matter

How can I achieve this? I'm considering drawing the given rect inside the context, calling `clip()`, and then drawing the bezier path. But I'm not certain that will actually improve performance, because perhaps behind the scenes, the full path is drawn, and then clipped to.

Comment: Are you actually _having_ performance problems, or are you just _guessing_ that you _might_ have them?

Comment: @matt the app is quite complex/doing a lot already, especially in the background. The paths I'm drawing have thousands of curved bezier points, and drawing happens on a MapKit overlay - which makes many small sized drawRect calls (up to about 25), rather than one big one. I don't think I'm worrying about this over nothing :)

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. Did you measure? With Instruments?

Comment: @matt Seems like Apple thinks I should be worry about this (see link below). The CPU is already running at 100% some of the time (using many threads), and I've done a lot (weeks worth) of work to keep the main thread clear and the app running smoothly when under heavy load. I haven't implemented the feature I'm working on yet - but every bit of performance counts. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/DrawingTips/DrawingTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH18-SW1

Comment: @matt to quote Apple's documentation: `Drawing is a relatively expensive operation on any platform, and optimizing your drawing code should always be an important step in your development process.`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to break your UIBezierPath up into smaller parts such that each drawRect draws 1 part that fits the rect?

Comment: @AllanPoole hmm, MapKit has lots of different zoom levels, so the rects change size. I could break it up into smaller parts for sure, although it'd be arbitrary as to where I break it up. If there's no simple or 'correct' way to do what I want then yeah, I guess I should look into that.

Comment: It's hard to comment accurately without having a better idea of the implementation, but I would lean toward breaking up the path into smaller chunks. And then finding the chunk(s) that fit in a given rectangle.

Comment: @AllanPoole thanks, ok cool. I'm drawing vehicle trails with thousands of points, and then interpolate between those for a smooth result. There could be more than one vehicle on the map at any time too. I'm clipping to each bezier path using `replacePathWithStrokedPath()`, then applying a gradient over the bounding box of each path. I can definitely split it up, I'll just need to do a bit of work, and figure out the best logic for doing so. Unless there's a better answer, sounds like this might be the way to go

Comment: Not to be too pedantic but drawing with UIBezierPath is not using Core Graphics. UIBezierPath is part of UIKit.

Comment: @GlennHowes isn't drawRect Core Grahics, and UIBezierPath just a container class for a CGPath? I'm using a CGContext for drawing and calling CGContextClip etc which is where Core Graphics comes in.

Comment: drawRect is a method on UIView so not part of Core Graphics. It's true that UIBezierPath wraps a CGPath (or at least acts like it does), so I can see where you were coming from.... As for your problem, you should break it up into smaller chunks as suggested above. If the path rendering has to walk through the entire path to figure out what is in the clip region its going to be slower than if it was dealing with a more targeted size. Heck if it was just Northern Hemisphere it would be half as complicated.

Comment: @GlennHowes the drawing inside drawRect uses a CGContext... anyhow, thanks, yeah currently I'm planning on splitting the path up into 20 point chunks, and making each of the chunks a different bezier path.